# About LSTM understanding on Keras

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I was wondering how was working LSTM under Keras.

Let's take an example.
I have maximum sentence length of 3 words.
Example : 'how are you'
I vectorize each words in a vector of len 4. So I will have a shape (3,4)
Now, I want to use an lstm to do translation stuff. (Just an example)

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(3,4), return_sequences=True))
model.summary()
```

I'm going to have an output shape of (3,1) according to Keras.

```python
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_16 (LSTM)               (None, 3, 1)              24        
=================================================================
Total params: 24
Trainable params: 24
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And this is what I don't understand.

Each unit of an LSTM (With return_sequences=True to have all the output of each state) should give me a vector of shape (timesteps, x)
Where timesteps is 3 in this case, and x is the size of my words vector (In this case, 4)

So, why I got an output shape of (3,1) ?
I searched everywhere, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of what the LSTM should return is not right. The output dimensionality doesn't need to match the input dimensionality. Concretely, the first argument of [keras.layers.LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) corresponds to the dimensionality of the output space, and you're setting it to 1.

In other words, setting:

`model.add(LSTM(k, input_shape=(3,4), return_sequences=True))`

will result in a `(None, 3, k)` output shape.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, if I understand it, you mean that the first argument refer to the number of neurons into the different gates of the LSTM ? So, whatever is the input, the output and the context vector will have the argument len. Is that right ?

Comment: Right, the first argument refers to the output dimensionality of the LSTM gates, and the output dimensionality doesn't depend on the input dimensionality.

Comment: @Pusheen_the_dev if the answer has been helpful, kindly accept and/or upvote it - answers take up valuable time for respondents